# If using CascadeType.ALL I get Detached error. If not, get Transient error

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, cascade, transient

**SOLVED:**

I have three related classes in the entity but only one receives value (according to the option that is selected). In this case, the option that have value is given Detached and the other two are Transient. The solution was set Null for not receiving value through Set. For example:

```
public void setSecretary(Secretary secretary) {
    if (secretary != null && secretary.getId() != null) {
        this.secretary = secretary;
    } else {
        this.secretary = null;
    }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

Using @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER):

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Class
```

Not using @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER):

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Class.subclass -> Subclass
```

What can I do to solve this?

**EDIT:
Transient Error:**

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: br.com.pack.converte.model.Verificacao.secretaria -> br.com.pack.converte.model.Secretaria
org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:380)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:177)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:162)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:153)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:89)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.save(Unknown Source)
br.com.pack.controller.VerificacaoController.salvar(VerificacaoController.java:89)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:61)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InstantiateInterceptor.intercept(InstantiateInterceptor.java:48)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:67)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:83)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.java:96)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:59)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:69)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
br.com.pack.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:41)
```

**Detached Error:**

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.faee.converte.model.Departamento
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:836)
org.hibernate.ejb.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:53)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.persist(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:358)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:329)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.save(Unknown Source)
br.com.faee.controller.VerificacaoController.salvar(VerificacaoController.java:89)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:61)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:67)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.java:96)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:59)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InstantiateInterceptor.intercept(InstantiateInterceptor.java:48)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:83)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:69)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)
br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
br.com.faee.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:41)
```

Comment: Can you post some more client code ?

Comment: what operation you are doing and you do it per one transaction?